# How to convert a unicode character array back to unicode sequence in C++

Tags: c, unicode

My problem is how to convert a c/c++ string/chractor array to another string contain the unicode(UTF-16) escape sequence of original one

for example, I want to find a function F(char *ch) could do following function.

```
char a[10] = "\u5f53";
printf("a = %s\n",a);
char b[10];
b = F(a);   //<- F is the function I wanted
printf("b = %s\n",b);

-------- console will show -------
a = 張
b = \u5f53
```

Anyone has any Idea@@?~

thanks!!

ps: I tried to guess \u5f35 means the value store in a, but it is not indeed
the value of a[0] = -79 , a[1] = 105 ... So I don't know how to convert it back to the sequence of unicode.... Please give me a hane~ : )

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that uses the `iconv` library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iconv.h>

void F(char *a, char *b, size_t bufsize) {
  size_t in_len = strlen(a);
  size_t out_len = bufsize - 1;
  iconv_t cd = iconv_open("C99", "UTF-8");
  iconv(cd, &a, &in_len, &b, &out_len);
  *b = 0;
}

int main(void) {
  char a[10] = "\u5f53";
  printf("a = %s\n",a);
  char b[10];
  F(a, b, 10);   //<- F is the function I wanted
  printf("b = %s\n",b);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [_mbstowcs_s_l](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/eyktyxsx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I am not sure of how exactly the unicode point needs to be fed to the function... perhaps like you have ("\uxxxx") or maybe "&#xxxx"

Comment: yeah@@ I have checked _mbstowcs_s_l